# Laravel 5.1 Date Time from today

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My javascript client generates a date in the following format:

2016-05-26T07:00:00.000Z

How do I calculate a year from now?  I have tried using DateTime::add but had no luck.    Any suggestions?

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: Share your actual code so it can be corrected.

Comment: Evert - I tried various options on the URL, I have enclosed above.  The last one was :  $mydate = "2016-05-26T07:00:00.000Z";
$add_days = 7;
$mydate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($mydate) + (24*3600*$add_days));
echo $mydate;

Comment: I couldn't test the Carbon solution because of the memory limitations.  But  DateTime worked in Laravel.  use DateTime and then implemented the solution posted by Pedro below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2016-05-26T07:00:00.000Z');
$date->modify('+1 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z');
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/gRHfZ7)

Comment: very close but not quite there for Laravel.  I had to add use DateTime to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library like this:

```
$jsDate = '2016-05-26T07:00:00.000Z';
echo Carbon::parse($jsDate)->addYear(1)->toDateTimestring();
```

obviously if you need custom output format you should use `format` function like so:

```
echo Carbon::parse($jsDate)->addYear(1)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I am sure this a good answer but I couldn't install carbon as it started complaining about memory issues.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel you can use Carbon

```
Carbon::now()->addYears(n);
```